# SQL INSERT WITH JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, insert, rows

I have a problem with a mysql query.

These are my 2 tables:

`player_locations:`

```
ID |  playerid  | type | location
---|-----------------------
```

and `users:`

```
ID  | playername | [..]
----|--------------------
 1  | example1   | ...
```

I want to insert into `player_locations` following:

```
ID |  playerid  | type | location
---|-----------------------
 1 |     1      |  5   |  DOWNTOWN
```

And thats my query:

```
INSERT INTO player_locations (id, type, location)
  SELECT u1.ID as playerid,
        d.type,
        d2.location
  FROM users u1
  INNER JOIN users u2
    ON 1 = 1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 5 as type
        FROM DUAL) d
  INNER JOIN (SELECT "DOWNTOWN" as location
        FROM DUAL) d2
    ON 1 = 1
  WHERE u1.playername = "example1";
```

But when i have 6 rows in `users` it inserts 6 same rows in `player_locations`

Comment: What does your question have to do with `java` (tag removed)?

Comment: I'll use the query in java. I thought i should mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write this?

```
INSERT INTO player_locations(id, type, location)
  SELECT u.ID as playerid, 5 as type, 'DOWNTOWN' as location
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.playername = 'example1';
```

The self join doesn't make any sense.  You are not using any information from `u2` in your query, so it just multiplies the number of rows.  The extra joins for constants are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take the WHERE clause out, put your select inside the () on the insert and that should do it for you.

Comment: I need the WHERE clause because I have to get the ID of the playername in the WHERE clause

Comment: Isnt the ID being consumed at the start of the select statement? If you want it to get the id from all the rows under [user] you will have to remove the where, if you don't then it will fill [player_location] with the single result the select returns.